# How do I stop onpress function making new list of button on each press?

Tags: android, flutter, function, dart, flutter-layout

I have added a onpress function to a button list where I wanted that when I pressed a button from that list it will turn into another color permanantly and show it's text in the upper area. But when I press a button another set of button keep appearing like this. (https://youtu.be/kQP_i-lrgUw)

[image]

Here is my code :

```
class _SecondRouteState extends State<SecondRoute> {
  String newT = "";
  static String pressedText = "";
  List<ElevatedButton> buttonsList = [];
  bool _flag = true;
  List wordlist = []; 
  List shufflelist = [];

  List breakText() {
    newT = widget.text;
    var x = newT.split(" ");
    print(x);
    bool res = x.remove("");
    while (res == true) {
      res = x.remove("");
    }
    print(x);
    return x;
  }

  onButtonPressed(String buttonValue) {

    pressedText = pressedText + " " + buttonValue;
    print(pressedText);

  }

  List makeShuffle(List list) {
    List puranlist = list;
    puranlist.shuffle();

    return puranlist;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    wordlist = breakText(); 
    shufflelist = makeShuffle(wordlist);
  }

  List<Widget> _buildButtonsWithNames() {
    for (int i = 0; i < shufflelist.length; i++) {
      buttonsList.add(
        new ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => {
            setState(() {
              onButtonPressed(shufflelist[i]);
              _flag = !_flag;
            }),
          },
          child: Text(shufflelist[i]),
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              primary: _flag ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 20),
              textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          // style: ButtonStyle(
          //     overlayColor: getColor(Colors.white, Colors.teal),
          //     backgroundColor: getColor(Colors.blue, Colors.red)),
        ),
      );
    }
    return buttonsList;
  }

  MaterialStateProperty<Color> getColor(Color color, Color colorPressed) {
    final getColor = (Set<MaterialState> states) {
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
        return colorPressed;
      } else {
        return color;
      }
    };
    return MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(getColor);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            pressedText,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30.0,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Wrap(
                children: _buildButtonsWithNames(),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

I just want that when I press the button that button text will be shown on the top. No more list will appear.

Comment: `_buildButtonsWithNames` is called whenever your widget is rebuilt, and it always adds to `buttonsList`.  Your issue is not that you make a *new* `List` on each button press; your problem is that you keep adding buttons each button press.  Your problem would go away if you actually did create a new `List` each time (or if you cleared the existing `List` first).

Comment: Also, you should be aware that your `makeShuffle` function seems to intend to shuffle a copy of the argument `List`, but it actually just mutates it. `wordlist` and `shufflelist` then will end up being references to the same `List` object.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks. But I do not understand how I keep adding button on each press. I have found that whenever I add something in setstate function this happens.

Comment: Your `onPressed` callback calls `setState` which will trigger a rebuild of your widget.  Your widget's `build()` method will call `_buildButtonsWithNames()` which always appends new `ElevatedButtons` to `buttonsList`. `_buildButtonsWithNames()` then returns `buttonsList`, which then is used as an argument to `Wrap(children: ...)`.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks!! declared a new list and that solves the problem. Any idea on how I can change ```buttonsList[i]``` color? Currently if I press all the button of the list changes it's color

Comment: I don't know what your intended behavior for the colors is.